# DotNetNuke 6 - One with DNN skin development - collapsible panes

Tags: dotnetnuke, skin

In DNN earlier version, I found this kind of default behavior in skinning.

When there is no content in Left-Pane and Right-pane then both panes are collapse and Content-pane consumes all spaces of left and right pane.

But I have created new skin in DNN version 6.0.1 which does not support this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 3):

**Utilize DNNEmptyPane** - DNN adds "DNNEmptyPane" class to empty panes.

1) At the bottom of skin.css, add `.DNNEmptyPane{width:0}`. You must do this exactly.

2) Do not use the ID of the panes to set their width.

3) Using "skinname".css can cause some problems with DNNEmptyPane

4) Make sure that your skin.css file validates (proper closing tags, etc)

This class should automatically be applied to all panes that have no content.

**References**

- [Good Discussion about DNNEmptyPane](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/109/threadid/338561/scope/posts/threadpage/2.aspx)
- You can look at the MinimalExtropy skin from DNN 5 for an example of this concept